# Custom popups in iOS using storyboard views or separate nibs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, popup, storyboard

What is the most correct/efficient/up-to-date way to present a popup window in iOS?

A la TweetBot:

[image]

**Methods I've used:**

- Presented a popup from a separate nib and used loadNibNamed
- Presented a popup from the main storyboard with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier
- Created/Presented a popup purely programmatically*

*I'd rather not use this method because my popup has a fairly complicated custom UI

Also once I get the scene loaded from any of the methods above I don't know how to connect the UI elements in the popup with outlets/actions (Protocols? Delegates?)

If you could point me in the right direction for the most correct way of creating/showing/using a popup that would be fantastic.

Let me know if i'm being too vague, I can add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**:

Hm, Just saw your screenshot after entering my answer. Well to do that, you can use a the feature provided by UIAlertView. I am pretty sure that is how the TweetBot guys do it as well. This [link here shows a blog article](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation/) that will let you do what you need.

Unless you want to go crazy custom, there are couple of solution out there that let you accomplish it. Something [like this](http://maniacdev.com/2012/04/open-source-completely-customizable-iphone-uialertview-replacement-control/)

**DONE EDIT**

One thing you can use is the Segues. Assuming you are using StoryBoard and when you tap on a button and that brings in a pop up view, you can connect them through something like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ViewToBringIn"]) {
        ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.navigationItem.title = @"some title";
    }
}
```

Another way of using Segues could be through the StoryBoard UI. Click on the view you want, and that will bring up something like the screenshot in the Connection Inspector:

[image: Segues Connection Inspector]

However, if you are using a nib file, then you can still create them and push them into the view (according to the format you want) via code. Of course the design on the view is done through the Interface Builder.

Comment: So you suggest either 1) using an open source custom popup method or 2) customizing UIAlertView are the best methods for presenting a custom popup?

Comment: As of today, yes, I believe customizing UIAlertView would be one of the best approach, unless it does not give you enough functionality then try the open source tools (of course you will cite them appropriately on your project, won't you?).

Comment: Yeah hmm. Neither of these really solve what i'm trying to do. I want to create a custom view with buttons, text fields, custom graphics (separate nib or a storyboard view) and have the view present itself (popup style, i can write the animation) and using protocols/delegates link up the UI elements of my popup with the appropriate methods. I'm able to do all the UI/functionality programmatically but I don't want to do that--because of the custom complicated layout/graphics I would rather use an IB view (nib or storyboard)